# Reduce a one-hand weapon to a light weapon?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, optimization, weapons

Is there any way to reduce a weapon's category from one-handed to a light weapon? I.e. make a scimitar usable with Weapon Finesse?

Comment: There aren't a whole lot of scimitar-specific stuff in *D&D 3.5*. Is there a particular reason you want this?

Comment: Are you interested in solutions that can work for many kinds of one-handed weapons, or _just_ what will work for a scimitar? (People have noted in a meta discussion that this question reads ambiguously at the moment. You say "i.e.", and that just roughly means "as in", which would suggest just scimitar. Some people use it intending to mean "e.g.", which is "for example", which would suggest you're interested in solutions for _many_ kinds of one-handed weapon, and a scimitar is just one case.)

Comment: Could you please clarify whether this is for a scimitar specifically or one-handed weapons in general, and please write a little bit about why you want to do this? Those may seem like minor things, but in a system like D&D 3.5e those can change the solution significantly. I notice guessing and debating on these two points in comments and answers and that strongly indicates these are important points that need to be written clearly in the question. Thanks! We can get this reopened quickly once those are addressed.

Comment: Also whether you really need the weapon to become Light, or just to be usable with Weapon Finesse (those are two things, and there's more options for the latter than the former).

Answer (score 14):

For your *specific* example—changing a scimitar to a light weapon—this is a first-level class feature of the dervish:

> **Slashing Blades**: A dervish treats the scimitar as a light weapon (rather than a one-handed weapon) for all purposes, including fighting with two weapons. (*Complete Warrior* 25)

Unfortunately, dervish is a prestige class that requires a +5 BAB, so you need to be at least level 6 to take that first level.

Answer (score 11):

DMGII's Feycraft weapon special will allow Weapon Finesse on one-handed weapons for +1500 gp. It reduces damage by one size, though, and does not make the weapon Light for other purposes.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to do so, both ingame and concerning rule books used, is to take a smaller weapon size. So if you are a medium creature, take a small weapon.

A one-handed weapon one size smaller than the normal size for the user counts as a light weapon. So if your character is medium, a scimitar for a small character will count as a light weapon for your character.

Please note that a weapon of one size category smaller than normal also has a lower damage dice and a -2 penalty to hit.

You should also check out [Armor for Unusual Creatures](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/armor#TOC-Armor-for-Unusual-Creatures) since as a small creature the weapon costs the same but weighs half as much. This ruling should also apply to weapons.

Your final "small scimitar" to use with weapon finesse as a medium character would look like this:

> Scimitar: Slashing, Light, -2 to hit, 1d4 damage

It should be easy to get, any weapon smith should be able to forge one for the same price as a normal scimitar.

All the rules for this can be found in the Player's Handbook.

Comment: No, rules for armor should not automatically be cross-applied to weapons. In this case, there exists a perfectly-good rule for weapons, in a footnote on the Weapons table: “Weight figures are for Medium weapons. A Small weapon weighs half as much, and a Large weapon weighs twice as much.”